# Getting multiple hashes from redis using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, redislabs

I need get about 10k hashes from redis server. Since there is no command to get multiple hashes in redis I was iterating through the all keys using `db.HashGetAllAsync()` call and then waiting all tasks to complete. Even though it worked I saw a dramatic latency spike on RedisLabs dashboard during these calls.

Is there any ways to get many hashes at the same time? Maybe there is any `ConnectionMultiplexer` settings that may help in this situation?

Comment: Are you running multiple invocations of this call, then awaiting all of the results to be returned? If so, how many concurrent connections are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no varadic `hgetall`, so yes: the simplest approach would be to pipeline a huge number of individual `hgetall`. The only other thing you could *even possibly do* would be to use a Lua script (`eval`/`evalsha`) to generate multiple items in each item, but I can't see how this would reduce server load or bandwidth any, so it doesn't seem to be worth trying!

Either way, yes: this will generate some work on the server.

Comment: I guess using Lua script in situation where I'm trying to get 10k hashes would put other redis calls to queue and increase latency even more.

Comment: @pauliusnrk yep, I'd guess so too; your *best bet* here, IMO, would be to do the bulk hash read from a slave